# Deploy smart contract with metamask ethers.js and ganache

Tags: metamask, contract-deployment, ethers.js, ganache, smart-contract-wallets

I want to deploy smart contracts on front-end with metamask address as deployer.
To do that, I first compile the smart contract with Remix and put the json output on my React project (I use Ganache to deploy locally).

After that, I follow the erthers.js doc as follow:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
const signer = provider.getSigner()

factory = new ContractFactory(ContractJson.abi, ContractJson.data.bytecode, signer)
contract = await factory.deploy("Test", "TT");
console.log(contract.address)
console.log(contract.deployTransaction)
console.log(await contract.deployTransaction.wait())
```

At execution nothing is logged and the contract is not deployed.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong/missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used the Hardhat local node and I was trying to send a transaction via MetaMask. MetaMask didn't notify me that it couldn't connect to the local node and just silently waited forever.

To fix this, ensure that there is a connection to your node from MetaMask:

1. Add a network into MetaMask with the correct RPC URL (e.g. http://localhost:8545/) and Chain ID (e.g. 31337).
2. Switch to that network in MetaMask.
3. Ensure that the local node is running (e.g. run `npx hardhat node`)
4. Ensure that it is reachable (e.g. check via `curl localhost:8545`)

Also check the web console, maybe there are some error messages.